# "minifyEnabled true" gives me issue, why so?

Tags: android, proguard

when I am setting minifiyEnabled to true in my any variant (debug or release) it gives me below error -

```
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
Warning:library class android.webkit.WebView depends on program class android.net.http.SslCertificate
Warning:library class android.webkit.WebViewClient depends on program class android.net.http.SslError
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory depends on program class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning:library class org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning:there were 176 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:there were 23 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
Warning:there were 6 unresolved references to program class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProductionDebug'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

**It is working fine in emulator or device if its lolipop or higher.**

My problem resolved if i disable or make minifyEnabled to false, but I don't really want so.

My gradle tool is **build:gradle:2.3.0'**

And **multiDexEnabled true**

Note - I am not keeping any class or attribute in my **proguard-rules.pro** file.

Comment: Please remove all the warnings first as suggested in the logs

Comment: I think you need to configure proguard rule for retrofit.

Comment: The retrofit does use reflection feature of Java, so it needs some names and attributes to remain same as in source. You must set up proguard to ignore those while obfuscating. That obviously means that some parts of your code will be not obfuscated, so you should rather pay attention which parts are set as that, and keep there just minimal part of code (mostly just some empty classes holding values with get/set (or just public fields)), and move remaining implementation details into classes which can be obfuscated. Even obfuscated code is still well readable for good coder, don't bother much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of recherches and experiments I have got the solution. We have to add **keep** and **dontwarn** statments in our **proguard-rules.pro** file -

```
# Retrofit 1.X
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn rx.**

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

# If in your rest service interface you use methods with Callback argument.
-keepattributes Exceptions

# If your rest service methods throw custom exceptions, because you've defined an ErrorHandler.
-keepattributes Signature



# Proguard configuration for amazon Jackson 2.x (fasterxml package instead of codehaus package)

-keep class com.amazonaws.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.amazonaws.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.**
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**


-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-dontwarn org.mockito.**
-dontwarn sun.reflect.**
-dontwarn android.test.**



-dontwarn org.hamcrest.**
-dontwarn android.test.**
-dontwarn android.support.test.**

-keep class org.hamcrest.** {
   *;
}

-keep class org.junit.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.junit.**

-keep class junit.** { *; }
-dontwarn junit.**

-keep class sun.misc.** { *; }
-dontwarn sun.misc.**


-keep public class android.net.http.SslError
-keep public class android.webkit.WebViewClient

-dontwarn android.webkit.WebView
-dontwarn android.net.http.SslError
-dontwarn android.webkit.WebViewClient


-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
```

Note - I followed the warnings in messages and by picking one by one put my proguard rule accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

if you are define proper **proguard** rules and still issue then please             **minifyEnabled true** use only for **application** level for other **module** use             **minifyEnabled false**.

Also if any lintError found and its not possible to solve then use below code

```
lintOptions {
checkReleaseBuilds false
// Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
// but continue the build even when errors are found:
abortOnError false
```

}

I have checked that and its works after so much effort.